# How to get number of replicas of StatefulSet Kubernetes

Tags: kubernetes, google-cloud-platform, google-kubernetes-engine, autoscaling, statefulset

I am trying to autoscale my StatefulSet on Kubernetes. In order to do so, I need to get the current number of pods.

When dealing with deployments:

```
kubectl describe deployments [deployment-name] | grep desired | awk '{print $2}' | head -n1
```

This outputs a number, which is the amount of current deployments.

However, when you run

```
kubectl describe statefulsets
```

We don't get back as much information. Any idea how I can get the current number of replicas of a stateful set?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

you should be running one of the below command

```
master $ kubectl get statefulsets
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
web       4         4         2m
master $
master $ kubectl get sts
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE
web       4         4         2m


number of running pods
---------------------
master $ kubectl describe sts web|grep Status
Pods Status:        4 Running / 0 Waiting / 0 Succeeded / 0 Failed

another way
------------
master $ kubectl get sts --show-labels
NAME      DESIRED   CURRENT   AGE       LABELS
web       4         4         33s       app=nginx

master $ kubectl get po -l app=nginx
NAME      READY     STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
web-0     1/1       Running   0          56s
web-1     1/1       Running   0          55s
web-2     1/1       Running   0          30s
web-3     1/1       Running   0          29s

master $ kubectl get po -l app=nginx --no-headers
web-0     1/1       Running   0         2m
web-1     1/1       Running   0         2m
web-2     1/1       Running   0         1m
web-3     1/1       Running   0         1m
master $
master $
master $ kubectl get po -l app=nginx --no-headers | wc -l
4
```

Comment: Answer is perfect! How can I simply get the number "4" from CURRENT?

Answer (score 10):

```
 kubectl get sts web -n default -o=jsonpath='{.status.replicas}'
```

This also works with .status.readyReplicas and .status.currentReplicas

From [github.com/kubernetes](https://github.com/kubernetes/kubernetes/blob/master/pkg/apis/apps/types.go):

> // replicas is the number of Pods created by the StatefulSet controller.
>   Replicas int32
>
> // readyReplicas is the number of Pods created by the StatefulSet controller that have a Ready Condition.
>   ReadyReplicas int32
>
> // currentReplicas is the number of Pods created by the StatefulSet controller from the StatefulSet version
>   // indicated by
>   currentRevision.
>   CurrentReplicas int32